# NSNotification to be called like in a For loop

Tags: iphone, nsnotification

I have a parser class and a view controller class. In the parser class i am sending a request and receiving an asynchronous response. I want to download the same several times but while sending different parameters each time. I have registered an observer in the class:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dataDownloadComplete:) name:OP_DataComplete object:nil];
```

and then post a notification in :

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)
```

connection method of the parser class.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:OP_DataComplete object:nil];
```

I can't enclose the observer inside a For loop. What better alternative is there? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why can't you enclose it in the for loop?

Comment: why you want to enclose it in a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably do not need a for loop at all. As you said you send a request asynchroniously, so just send it in your observer code instead of making a for loop. Then you get back to your observer after response is downloaded.

Comment: Thanks Oleg! Now i have this piece of code:
    -(void)dataDownloadComplete
    {
    if(parameterN<10)
    { 
      if(conditionismet)
      {
         [self callWebservice:parameterN];
         N++;
      }
      else
      {
         N++; 
      }
    }
    }       


The callback stops after conditionismet. When the condition is not met the callback is not entered, can i make the code enter the callback at such times as well instead of exiting completely. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: @kumar, Sorry I did not get your question. If you want to call your callBack regardless of condition - just do it :). Don't use a condition or add a call to else section.